# Rails rake task: accepts local variable on one line, but rejects it on the next

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rake task that changes the meta tags that are defined in the controller.  I found some help [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/194046), but I'm still getting an error.  When I try to run this rake task, ruby doesn't like line 11, the one that begins "found = ".  I get this error.

```
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `line' for main:Object
/Users/********/lib/tasks/meta_tags.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is what the task looks like.  I'm confused as to why "line" is interpreted correctly on the first preceding line (10), but blows up on 11.  Any ideas?

```
require 'rake'
namespace :meta_tags do
  desc 'changes the meta tags'
  task :update => :environment do  
    regex = /^@meta_tag/
    found = false
    file = File.open('app/controllers/site_controller.rb', 'w')
    file.each_line |line|
      replace_line(line) if(found)
      found = true if(line =~ regex)
    end

    def replace_line(line)
      meta_tags = MetaTag.all.map { |tag| tag["tag"] }
      new_tag = meta_tags.sample(1)[0]
      line = "@meta_tag = #{new_tag}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `do` to your iteration... Nor sure that it is related, but ruby interpreter  sometimes throws weird errors because of it:

```
file.each_line do |line|
  replace_line(line) if(found)
  found = true if(line =~ regex)
end
```

**Update:**

Also, seems like you need to close task block:

```
require 'rake'
namespace :meta_tags do
  desc 'changes the meta tags'
  task :update => :environment do  
    regex = /^@meta_tag/
    found = false
    file = File.open('app/controllers/site_controller.rb', 'w')
    file.each_line do |line|
      replace_line(line) if(found)
      found = true if(line =~ regex)
    end
  end

  def replace_line(line)
    meta_tags = MetaTag.all.map { |tag| tag["tag"] }
    new_tag = meta_tags.sample(1)[0]
    line = "@meta_tag = #{new_tag}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow. Good eye.  Thank you for your terrific attention to detail!